# Add points to geom_sf() and color polygons by number of occurrences

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a plot created with `ggplot() + geom_sf()`, like so:

```
library(eurostat)
library(sf)
# get European country borders
SHP_0 <- get_eurostat_geospatial(resolution = 10, 
                                 nuts_level = 2, 
                                 year = 2016) %>% 
  filter(!NUTS_ID %in% c("IS"))

SHP_0 %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-15, 40), labels = function(x) paste0(x, '\u00B0', "E")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c( 35, 75), labels = function(x) paste0(x, '\u00B0', "N")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#42BFED", colour = "#42BFED"))
```

On ths plot, I would now like to also add points contained in a dataframe like this:

```
df_points <- tibble(lat=c(40, 45, 50), lon=c(-1,  0, 10))
```

Since the actual data set is larger, I would like to

1. add each point separately and
2. in color each sub-unit (nuts-level) depending on the number of points in that data set

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
ggplot(data=SHP_0) + 
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(data=df_points, aes(x=lon, y=lat), size=1, shape=23, fill="darkred") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-15, 40), labels = function(x) paste0(x, '\u00B0', "E")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c( 35, 75), labels = function(x) paste0(x, '\u00B0', "N")) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#42BFED", colour = "#42BFED"))
```

achieves the former (adding points).